# Android String value out of if else statement

Tags: java

I'm writing a simple app taht scrape some data from a web site.
I'm able to get data and put this in a String value, but as for the costructor of the web site, the value has different class name depending if the value is negative or positive.

My question is: how to assign the value at my string if one of the value get from web site is null?

I try with an if-else statement but isn't work to pass correct value at my ParseAdapter.

My code:

```
                    String percentage_red = element.select( perc_red ).text();
                    String percentage_green = element.select( perc_green ).text();

                    if(percentage_red == null){
                        String percentage = percentage_red;
                    }else {
                        String percentage = percentage_green;
                    }
                    parseItems.add( new ParseItem( name,price,percentage ) );
```

percentage isn't export to my adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `percentage` variable outside the if..else statement, so you can access that variable outside of if..else :

```
    String percentage;

    if(percentage_red == null){
        percentage = percentage_red;
    }else {
        percentage = percentage_green;
    }
    parseItems.add( new ParseItem( name,price,percentage ) );
```

Comment: Thank You! I solved my problem due to many hours to scrape data :-)